# How to push npm project from jenkins to oneops

Tags: jenkins, npm, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, oneops

I have an npm project which I am using Jenkins for Continuous Integration. So I achieved build automation in Jenkins. Right now I am struggling how to push the build output to Oneops. I browsed couldn't find any solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say you are building an NPM project can you clarify what you mean?  Are you building a client-side application that needs to publish an artifact?  Or, are you publishing an NPM module?   My answer is going to be different depending on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  Let's say you are deploying something like a React application that you are building in Jenkins.  Maybe you run "npm run build" and your build creates an optimized application in the build/ subdirectory?

This is a process I run several times a day in response to a CI build.

1. I do this now in Jenkins, Jenkins run the build "npm run build."
2. I use a simple Maven deploy-file task to upload a ZIP archive to Nexus. (See the documentation for Maven deploy-file here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html)
3. Then I configure the OneOps artifact component to download from Nexus - http://oneops.com/user/design/artifact-component

Admittedly, this may not be the NPM-focused way of publishing artifacts, but I found the using NPM to publish artifacts to Nexus had some limitations that I couldn't accept.

To take this a step further, I've configured by Jenkins build to call out to OneOps and trigger an environment variable update that triggers the deployment of code to OneOps.